# Angular is not running change detection through ChangeDetectorRef

Tags: angular, angular2-changedetection

I have a child component with an input variable say 'name'. It has some initial value through data binding via Parent component. Now when I change the value of 'name' from inside the child component itself, Angular doesn't know. How do I let Angular know about that change?

From what I read online, I tried using `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()` or `ChangeDetectorRef.markForCheck()` it doesn't seem to work. I think I am missing something.

Here is the stackblitz  [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eudvws?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts) for this issue. If you change the name from within child component and then again try to change the name from parent component it won't change as Angular still thinks it is bound to the value provided by Parent component earlier. But I changed it from inside the Child component. How do I fix this?

Comment: Your stackblitz link isn't working

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `ngOnChanges` lifeCycle hook to reflect the change made in parent component to child component.

Eg:

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if (changes.name != undefined) {
      this.name = changes.name.currentValue           
    }
}
```

Also in StackBiltz I can see that you have binded `Input` like this:

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
```

Modify it to:

```
<hello [name]="name"></hello>
```

To  Change Parent from child:

**Child Component**:

`@Output() ChangeName = new EventEmitter()`

```
changeMe() {
     this.ChangeName.emit('Angular from child')
}
```

**Parent Component:**

```
 <hello [name]="name" (ChangeName)="name = $event"></hello>
```

Comment: Can you share me the modified stackblitz with me? It doesn't seem to work. Also, I haven't made any change in the parent component. I made change in the child component which parent is not aware of, hence it doesn't change value when I click .

Comment: Hey..  i am unable to save in StackBiltz.  Can you share emailid, I will send app component and hello component code

Comment: I know we can use @Output, but consider a scenario where I don't want to emit an event then how can we inform Angular?

Comment: To change anything in parent from child, output is necessary. Give me a scenario as example where u can't to emit an event

Answer (score 0):

For Angular to detect the change, you need to change the **reference** of the variable passed to the input. You can easily trigger the change, by assigning a copy of the object.

**component.html**

```
<button (click)="onNameChangeClicked()"> Change Name From Parent</button>
```

**component.ts**

```
  onNameChangeClicked() {
    this.name = Object.assign('Angular from Parent ',{});
  }
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6wt5yn?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Answer (score 0):

**ngOnChanges**

ngOnChanges Lifecycle will run only if the bounded input property value is different from current value

**Example:**

```
 OnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges){
   if(changes.name.currentValue !== changes.name.previousValue){
    //if the bound value is diffrent from currentValue then ngOnChanges will be triggered
  }
```

Use **ngDoCheck** lifecycle hook.

> A callback method that performs change-detection, invoked after the
>   default change-detector runs.